# Is there a way of understanding the finite number of regular polytopes in dimension other than 2 by means of Lie groups?

Tags: geometry, lie-groups, polytopes

I think I have heard of something like this but I do not know. In 3D I know of the graph theoretic formulation but I am wondering if there is an algebraic understanding.